# Getting PDFBox IO Exception: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read, while using PDF as background image in Apache FOP

Tags: pdfbox, apache-fop

I am generating a pdf file using Apache FOP - 2.5.x and I need to use some existing pdf as background images. I am using fop-pdf-images-2.3 to enable this. Fop-pdf-images uses PDFBox 2.0.20 to enable FOP to read pdf file as background image.

But I am sometimes getting this error

```
Error on PDF page: https://s2.q4cdn.com/498544986/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.PDFBoxImageHandler.handleImage(PDFBoxImageHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImage(AbstractIFPainter.java:249)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImage(AbstractIFPainter.java:205)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingImageHandler(AbstractIFPainter.java:170)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImageUsingURI(PDFPainter.java:218)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:181)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.drawImage(IFRenderer.java:1301)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.drawImage(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:973)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.drawBackground(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:308)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.drawBackground(IFRenderer.java:1390)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.drawBackground(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:215)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.drawBackAndBorders(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:173)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.handleRegionTraits(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:128)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:373)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderRegionViewport(IFRenderer.java:738)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPageAreas(AbstractRenderer.java:345)
    at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderPage(AbstractRenderer.java:318)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderPage(IFRenderer.java:587)
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.addPage(RenderPagesModel.java:123)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(AbstractPageSequenceLayoutManager.java:316)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:243)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:139)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:362)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:190)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.endElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:263)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:610)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1718)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2883)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:660)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:774)
    ... 7 more

  Caused by: java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.checkClosed(COSStream.java:154)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:239)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:234)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.getContents(PDPage.java:157)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.PDFBoxAdapter.getContents(PDFBoxAdapter.java:460)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.PDFBoxAdapter.createStreamFromPDFBoxPage(PDFBoxAdapter.java:352)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.AbstractPDFBoxHandler.createStreamForPDF(AbstractPDFBoxHandler.java:111)
    at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.pdfbox.PDFBoxImageHandler.handleImage(PDFBoxImageHandler.java:71)
    ... 46 more
```

This error depends on the pageHeight and pageWidth in setup in my .fo file.

**Here is my .fo file for the same.**

```
{% set cardWidth = 8.3 %}
{% set cardHeight = 8 %}
{% set bleedLength = 0.125 %}
{% set totalWidth = cardWidth + 2 * bleedLength %}
{% set totalHeight = cardHeight + 2 * bleedLength %}

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="MyPick" page-width="{{ totalWidth }}in" page-height="{{ totalHeight }}in">
            <fo:region-body background-image="https://s2.q4cdn.com/498544986/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>


    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="MyPick">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="{{ bleedLength }}in" left="{{ bleedLength }}in" width="{{ cardWidth }}in"
             height="{{ cardHeight }}in">

                <fo:block-container display-align="center" margin-left="1.5in" margin-top="1.2in" margin-right="1.5in"
                height="6.539in">

                    <fo:block-container margin="0">

                        <fo:block font-family="Bookerly Display" text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)" font-size="160pt" line-height="1">
                            Header
                        </fo:block>

                        <fo:block font-family="Bookerly Display" margin-top="0.3in" text-align="start" color="rgb(255,255,255)" font-size="110pt" line-height="1">
                            SubHeader
                        </fo:block>

                    </fo:block-container>

                </fo:block-container>

                <fo:block margin-top="0.75in" margin-bottom="0.4175in" margin-right="0.39in" text-align="right" font-family="Arial" font-size="6pt"
                color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                    Footer
                </fo:block>

            </fo:block-container>

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

If I change my page cardWidth from 8.3 to 8.2, the same pdf renders properly. I don't understand why the issue happens for some dimensions but for some dimensions FOP is able to generate the file without any issues.

I am using this sample pdf file to test : https://s2.q4cdn.com/498544986/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf

Comment: The best would be to report this to FOP. But first try using the latest version. This error comes when a PDF is closed but reused, or a COSStream is closed prematurely.

Comment: Another thing is that this issue comes only when I call the method from terminal. If I run the main method from Intellij, everything works fine

Comment: Maybe a memory leak, i.e. that the caller doesn't hold the PDDocument, only the PDPage object. In that case the PDDocument might get closed by the gc. Or an outdated (buggy) jdk. Make sure to update to the latest jdk8 or whatever jdk you're using.

Comment: Yes, but why does changing the dimensions remove that bug. Is there any specific check with PDFBox does based on the dimensions?

Comment: No, size is irrelevant there for PDFBox (I don't know what FOP is doing - maybe additional or less pages depending on size?). Please check also if there is any output in the log before. PDFBox brings a warning if a PDDocument is closed by the gc.

Comment: So, I found when this issue happens. This issue happens when the page size of the pdf I am drawing with in FOP is either smaller or exactly equal to the page size of the background pdf. If I increase the dimensions of the MediaBox and CropBox of background pdf by 0.001, the issue doesn't occur. e.g. If my background pdf has MediaBox as [0 0 1260 630] and CropBox as [0 0 1260 630], then if I change them to [0 0 1260.001 630.001], FOP is able to render successfully. Any pointers, if you can give around the way PdfBox draws image using these boxes? Shouldn't the pdf with exact size be allowed ?

Comment: This sounds like a problem using a PDF and closing it prematurely. Likely a FOP problem. I'm a PDFBox committer but I know nothing about FOP and this is why I suggested to create a FOP issue in their JIRA tracker. I'm willing to work with them.